# Viddler automatically returning PHP file when uploading

Tags: php, video

I'm using the PHPviddler2 API on the website I'm building at the moment and something is confusing my users.

At the end of the upload via an upload form (code is below), my user recieves automatically an upload file.

```
<?php
    include('phpviddler/phpviddler.php');

    $user = '[censored]';
    $pass = '[censored]';
    $api_key = '[censored]';
    $callback_url = '/';

    $v = new Viddler_V2($api_key);

    $auth = $v->viddler_users_auth(array('user' => $user, 'password' => $pass));

    $sessionid = $auth['auth']['sessionid'];

    $prepare_resp = $v->viddler_videos_prepareUpload(array('sessionid' => $sessionid));

    $upload_server = $prepare_resp['upload']['endpoint'];
    $upload_token  = $prepare_resp['upload']['token'];
?>
<div id="viddler-form">
    <form method="post" action="<?= $upload_server ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="uploadtoken" value="<?= $upload_token ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="callback" value="<?= $callback_url ?>" />
        <table>
          <tr><td><label>Title:</label></td><td><input type="text" name="title" /></td><td>Band name or project name (Example: John Smith Band or John Smith Audition)</td></tr>
          <tr><td><label>Description:</label></td><td><input type="text" name="description" /></td><td>Type of band or project (Example: 5-piece cover band or Orchestra Audition Saxophone)</td></tr>
          <tr><td><label>Tags:</label></td><td><input type="text" name="tags" /></td><td>Keywords associated with your video (Example: johnsmith, orchestrasax)</td></tr>
          <tr><td><label>File:</label></td><td><input type="file" name="file" /></td><td>Choose your video (.mov .wmv .avi .mp4 .m4v .divx .mpg .mpeg)</td></tr>
          <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Upload" id="submit-button" /></td><td></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>

</div>
```

Is there a way to prevent that php file from being returned to my user?

EDIT: The action of the form is this adress: http://uploads1.viddler.com/viddler_upload/upload/uploadvideo.php. So I can't possibly modify it.

Also, the file returned contains this:

```
a:1:{s:5:"video";a:5:{s:2:"id";s:8:"1fade21b";s:5:"title";s:4:"test";s:11:"description";s:5:"test ";s:3:"url";s:33:"http://www.viddler.com/v/1fade21b";s:13:"thumbnail_url";s:54:"http://cdn-thumbs.viddler.com/thumbnail_2_1fade21b.jpg";}}
```

Comment: We would need to see the file that the form action is pointed to. That's where the problem is at.

Comment: That string is a serialized php array. Are you supposed to be using something like Curl to send the file from your own form handler?

Comment: Thing is, this file is getting downloaded by my user once the upload is completed. How could I intercept it to read it? Maybe it could be the key of it not being downloaded by my user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I downloaded the Viddler 2 php api, and they include an upload file example. I wasn't able to test the code below, but I think you need to be doing something like this.

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES) && file_exists($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
    include('phpviddler/phpviddler.php');

    $user = '[censored]';
    $pass = '[censored]';
    $api_key = '[censored]';
    $callback_url = '/';

    $v = new Viddler_V2($api_key);

    $auth = $v->viddler_users_auth(array('user' => $user, 'password' => $pass));

    $params = array(
      'sessionid'=>$user['auth']['sessionid'],
      'title'=>$_POST['title'], 
      'tags'=>$_POST['tags'],
      'description'=>$_POST['description'],
      'file'=>'@' . $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']
     );

    $sessionid = $auth['auth']['sessionid'];

    $prepare_resp = $v->viddler_videos_prepareUpload(array('sessionid' => $sessionid));
    $results = $v->viddler_videos_upload($params, $prepare_resp['upload']['endpoint']);

    header("Location: complete.php"); // redirect to a thank you page?
    exit;
}
?>
<div id="viddler-form">
    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table>
          <tr><td><label>Title:</label></td><td><input type="text" name="title" /></td><td>Band name or project name (Example: John Smith Band or John Smith Audition)</td></tr>
          <tr><td><label>Description:</label></td><td><input type="text" name="description" /></td><td>Type of band or project (Example: 5-piece cover band or Orchestra Audition Saxophone)</td></tr>
          <tr><td><label>Tags:</label></td><td><input type="text" name="tags" /></td><td>Keywords associated with your video (Example: johnsmith, orchestrasax)</td></tr>
          <tr><td><label>File:</label></td><td><input type="file" name="file" /></td><td>Choose your video (.mov .wmv .avi .mp4 .m4v .divx .mpg .mpeg)</td></tr>
          <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Upload" id="submit-button" /></td><td></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: That was the solution to the problem: Upload it to your server before uploading it to viddler. The file is returned to the server instead of the user.